# How to get MinIO metrics (/minio/v2/metrics/cluster)?

Tags: python, boto3, minio

Bases on the [MinIO documentation](https://min.io/resources/docs/MinIO-high-performance-object-storage.pdf) at page 14 following API is mentioned `/minio/v2/metrics/cluster` and `/minio/v2/metrics/node`.
But looks like these API available only for "Prometheus". And I have no clue to get those using python.


Of course if I try send request to `http://<host>:<port>/minio/v2/metrics/cluster` I get 403 error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code><Message>All access to this bucket has been disabled.</Message><Resource>/minio/v2/metrics/cluster</Resource><RequestId></RequestId><HostId><uuid-here></HostId></Error>
```

I've tried to generate presigned URL (like for GET object from bucket) but even with signature result is same as above.

Maybe someone know to reach that API(s)?
And how to do proper authentication for these endpoint without "Prometheus"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
import jwt  # pyJWT
import requests
import datetime

expired_at = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).timestamp()

token = jwt.encode(
    payload={
        "exp": expired_at,
        "sub": "<AccessKey>",
        "iss": "prometheus",
    },
    key="<SecretKey>",
    algorithm="HS512"
)

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token.decode()}"
}
response = requests.get(
    url="<schema>://<host>:<port>/minio/prometheus/metrics",
    headers=headers
)
```

How `mc` utility generates bearer token I found at https://github.com/minio/mc/blob/master/cmd/admin-prometheus-generate.go
URL `/minio/prometheus/metrics` was found during call to utility `mc admin prometheus generate test-minio`

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus just requests an HTTP resource, which presents metrics in plain text format. You can grab the same URL that prometheus would use and then parse it yourself.

If you look at [this document](https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-monitor-minio-using-prometheus.html), it describes how to configure authentication for the metrics endpoint.

> 2. Configure authentication type for Prometheus metrics
>
> MinIO supports two authentication modes for Prometheus either jwt or
> public, by default MinIO runs in jwt mode. To allow public access
> without authentication for prometheus metrics set environment as
> follows.
>
> ```
> export MINIO_PROMETHEUS_AUTH_TYPE="public" minio server ~/test
> ```

If you're running it in `jwt` mode (the default), the following
sections tells you how to generate a configuration that will show you
the appropriate bearer token to use for authentication:

> 3.1 Authenticated Prometheus config
>
> If MinIO is configured to expose metrics without authentication, you
> don't need to use mc to generate prometheus config. You can skip
> reading further and move to 3.2 section.
>
> The Prometheus endpoint in MinIO requires authentication by default.
> Prometheus supports a bearer token approach to authenticate
> prometheus scrape requests, override the default Prometheus config
> with the one generated using mc. To generate a Prometheus config for
> an alias, use mc as follows mc admin prometheus generate .
>
> The command will generate the scrape_configs section of the
> prometheus.yml as follows:
>
> ```
> scrape_configs:
> - job_name: minio-job
>   bearer_token: <secret>
>   metrics_path: /minio/v2/metrics/cluster
>   scheme: http
>   static_configs:
>   - targets: ['localhost:9000']
> ```

You can just use the bearer token and path from that configuration to
access your metrics. The bearer token should go into an
`Authorization` header (`Authorization: Bearer <token>`).

Comment: yeah, but trick is: I don't have Prometheus either `mc`(MinIO Client) utility. That is why I wonder to generate/retrieve Bearer token with python.

Comment: You don't need prometheus. Why not grab the minio client to generate the bearer token?

Comment: I've found way to generate this bearer token without "minio client" (but based on its code) :) Answer on question "Why not grab minio client" - env where it will be ran will not be able to install additional packages.